# how to fix g++ error during compilation in VSCode C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw-w64

```
[Running] cd "d:\C++ Programming\Practical Files\" && g++ DataType -o d:\C++ Programming\Practical Files\DataType && "d:\C++ Programming\Practical Files\"d:\C++ Programming\Practical Files\DataType
g++: error: Programming\Practical: **No such file or directory**
g++: error: Files\DataType: **No such file or directory**
```

May I know how to solve this error? I believe the problem lies in the configuration of the `g++` compiler.

Comment: You need to put quotes round your paths as they contain spaces

Comment: You have spaces in your path `C++ Programming` and `Practical Files`. Don't do that. You can solve the problem with quotes, but really it's easier to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: You need to surround *all* paths containing spaces with quotes. It's missing for the `-o` option.

Comment: On another note, have you really named your source file `DataType`, without any kind of suffix (like `.cpp`)? Then your build command will *overwrite* it with the executable file. And *if* you have a suffix then you need to specify it when listing the source file, otherwise the compiler won't find the source file.

Comment: Attention to detail is missing in both the command line _and_ the question.

Comment: There part on your text ```\Practical Files\"```. Don't do that. I mean when you put \ before " it affect on your quotes, so " no longer end your string, so everytime when you want to use \ as symbol, use \\ instead. If you want to know more about it, google about [escape charecters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Comment: Can you add some of the source code?